# Devexpress Gridview how get row value in decimal type cell?

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I have a grid control and I wanna get the value of the selected row. I could get the value of varchar type cell in row but I'm having trouble in getting the value for cell in decimal type.

Here's my code for every row click:

```
private void gridView1_RowClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowClickEventArgs e)
    {

        var productPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "product_price").ToString());

        MessageBox.Show(productPrice.ToString());
    }
```

For more info the `product_price` column is set to be in decimal type with length of (10,2) so the value its displaying is like `13,233.00`

Thank you I hope you can help me to solve this problem

Comment: What trouble are you getting? Does it throw an exception or something else?

Comment: Hmm I forgot to say . Yes it throws an exception with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Please help me

Comment: Your code worked on my machine, but only on standard view without grouping. Are you applying grouping on this gridview?

Comment: I believe the problem occurs on the data type in my mysql database. the decimal is set to (10,2) . Maybe it's the problem but right now I will now change it to int.

Comment: I use decimal(10,2) too on my datasource and it worked unless I apply grouping. Could you attach a screenshot of your grid at runtime?

Comment: Couple things I notice, if "product_price" doesn't match up to the name, it's not going to know which column to look at. Also, not sure about the configuration of your grid, but if the column is set to take decimal values, you might not need that conversion. I know the Gridviews will tend to "make sense of the data" they are given without much help, so it could very well already be a decimal. Don't think this would throw the null error though.

Comment: Another thing, as far as the column goes: I haven't tried your code, and it may very well work, but I usually refer to columns like this - gridview1.Columns.ColumnByFieldName("fieldName") or gridview1.Columns.ColumnByName("name")

Answer (score 0):

My first thought:  Is there no focused row?  Add this and see if it fixes the issue:

```
if (gridView1.SelectedRowsCount == 0)
    return;
```

That wasn't the issue?  Okay, add this to your code and set a breakpoint:

```
object o = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "product_price");
Type t = o.GetType();
```

When you add a watch (or hover) over `t`, does it say System.Decimal or String?

If it's a decimal, you should be in good shape, and what I would suggest is to just change the code to the following:

```
var productPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(
    gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "product_price"));
```

The only thing I omitted was the `ToString()`, so we can let the Convert function apply against the (raw) object.  I don't know how or why, and it actually seems like a long shot, but maybe `ToString()` is formatting the output in accordance with the grid display.

I'm guessing that is not the case, and your original supposition is correct in that the data coming from MySQL is actually formatted as a string, or your C# code is reading it as a string.  If this is the case, run the actual SQL and see what datatype is being rendered.  Is it numeric?  If so, is your C# reading it as numeric (`reader.GetDecimal(x)`) or, perhaps is there a `reader.GetValue(x).ToString()` that is ignoring datatypes?

In other words, is MySQL adding the formatting and sending a string, or is your C# changing a decimal to a string?  Find out what's doing that and put a stop to it.

You can certainly unformat the string and then convert to a decimal, but that seems like a long, LONG path to your end goal.